# Create long[] Array with Stringbuilder

Tags: java, arrays, string, long-integer, stringbuilder

I want to create a long[] Array with the Stringbuilder, but with this code i get  "java.lang.NumberFormatException:"

```
protected long[] getpattern(int numbercount, int value) {
        StringBuilder longstringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while(numbercount > 0) {
            longstringbuilder.append("100, ");
            longstringbuilder.append(value + ", ");
            numbercount--;
        }
            longstringbuilder.append("100");

        String longstring = longstringbuilder.toString();

            long[] pattern = new long[] {Long.parseLong(longstring)};




        return pattern;

    }
```

How can i fix that? 
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Why do you think that your syntax is going to work? You are making an array with a single item in it, and the item comes from parsing a long and incorrect string, which causes the exception. Use a list instead of string builder.

Comment: Why would you use a type designed for manipulating *text* to build an array of *numbers*? What are you trying to accomplish here? Why not use `long[] array = new long[numbercount];` and then populate it in a loop? (Or `numbercount * 2` if you want a value of 100 between each `value` value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how many elements there will be in the array: two times `numbercount`, plus 1. So just build that array:

```
long[] values = new long[2*numbercount+1];
for (int a = 0; a < numbercount; ++a) {
  values[2*a+0] = 100;
  values[2*a+1] = value;
}
values[values.length-1] = 100;
```

There is no need to involve `StringBuilder` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'longstringbuilder' reference contains nothing but a String with numbers, commas and spaces. You can parse a String which is %100 number, but in your case you have commas and spaces too.

There are several workarounds, for example you could split the String: `String[] stringArray = longstringbuilder.split(", ");` and then you can parse each item of your stringArray, since it will contain only numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `StringBuilder` looks like the long way round. Using a `Stream` would be much simpler:

```
protected long[] getpattern(int numbercount, int value) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numbercount).mapToLong(i -> value).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Or if the OP isn't comfortable with that, just constructing the array and populating it with a `for` loop would be really, really simple.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a Winter Bash hat for getting a comment from @JonSkeet :-)

Comment: Also, one-liner FTW!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the commas and spaces in your string. I am using trim in this example but you could probably just split on ", ".

```
protected long[] getpattern(int numbercount, int value) {
    StringBuilder longstringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while(numbercount > 0) {
        longstringbuilder.append("100, ");
        longstringbuilder.append(value + ", ");
        numbercount--;
    }
    longstringbuilder.append("100");

    String longstring = longstringbuilder.toString();
    String[] tokens = longstring.split(",");
    long[] pattern = new long[tokens.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        pattern[i] = Long.parseLong(tokens[i].trim());
    }

    return pattern;
}
```

Comment: This works fine, because there should be a 100 between every other value. Therefore twice as much numbers